# Discount label issue if simple and downloadable product in cart

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

I have a 10% Shopping Cart Rule on my store. Let's say this can be applied to all products.

The only action is to apply a 10 per cent discount to the product price. No conditions. The label is "10% off"

Let's say I have:
Simple Product A - £10.00
Simple Product B - £20.00
Downloadable Product C - £5.00

If I have just Product A and B in my cart (simple), the discount row in my cart totals reads:

```
Subtotal: £30.00
Discount (10% off): -£3.00
```

If I have just Product C in my cart (downloadable), the discount row in my cart totals reads:

```
Subtotal: £5.00
Discount (10% off): -£0.50
```

Both of the above are fine and exactly what I want.

**BUT** if I have Product A and C (simple AND downloadable), the discount row in my cart totals reads:

```
Subtotal: £15.00
Discount: -£1.50
```

Where has the "10% off" label gone?! I have disabled all other promotional rules so there's no conflict, just for some reason the discount label seems to not show if a simple AND a downloadable product are in the cart.

Has anyone experienced the same problem and found a fix? Thanks!

I'm using Magento CE 1.7.0.2

Comment: check for these `$code = $address->getCouponCode();` from @david's reply

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that this is not a complete answer but in the file: `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Discount` you can see the following code:

```
$title = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Discount');
$code = $address->getCouponCode();
if (strlen($code)) {
    $title = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Discount (%s)', $code);
}
```

I would suggest this is the code you are looking for. As to why the there is no coupon code I am not sure but this should be a good start for debugging.

If not I would suggest looking for `Discount (%s)` as this the string you are looking for.